# Ionic is it possible to console the value of stripe card fields

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, ionic4

I am using stripe in my application i need to save the user credit card info is it any way to console the values like cardnumber , exp date, and cvc ?

Here is html code

```
<div *ngIf="checkoutData.form.payment_method =='stripe'" class="stripe-payment">
  <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
    <div class="form-row">

      <div id="card-element">
        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
      </div>

      <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
      <div id="card-errors" class="card-error" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the onclick function

```
async onClickStripeSubmit() {
    var ownerInfo = {
        owner: {
            name: this.checkoutData.form.billing_first_name + ' ' + this.checkoutData.form.billing_last_name,
            address: {
                line1: this.checkoutData.form.billing_address_1,
                city: this.checkoutData.form.billing_city,
                postal_code: this.checkoutData.form.billing_postcode,
                country: 'US',
            },
            email: this.checkoutData.form.billing_email
        },
    };
    if (!this.checkoutData.form.shipping) {
            this.checkoutData.form.shipping_first_name = this.checkoutData.form.billing_first_name;
            this.checkoutData.form.shipping_last_name = this.checkoutData.form.billing_last_name;
            this.checkoutData.form.shipping_company = this.checkoutData.form.billing_company;
            this.checkoutData.form.shipping_address_1 = this.checkoutData.form.billing_address_1;
            this.checkoutData.form.shipping_address_2 = this.checkoutData.form.billing_address_2;
            this.checkoutData.form.shipping_city = this.checkoutData.form.billing_city;
            this.checkoutData.form.shipping_country = this.checkoutData.form.billing_country;
            this.checkoutData.form.shipping_state = this.checkoutData.form.billing_state;
            this.checkoutData.form.shipping_postcode = this.checkoutData.form.billing_postcode;
        }
        this.buttonSubmit = true;
        this.PlaceOrder = "Placing Order";
        this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
            message: 'Loading...',
            translucent: true,
            animated: true,
            backdropDismiss: true
        });
        await this.loading.present();
        console.log(this.cardElement);
        this.stripe.createSource(this.cardElement, ownerInfo).then((result) => {
        console.log(ownerInfo);
        console.log(this.cardElement);
        console.log(result);
            if (result.error) {
                this.loading.dismiss();
                // Inform the user if there was an error
                var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                this.checkoutData.form.stripe_source = result.source.id;
                 console.log(this.checkoutData.form.stripe_source);
                this.stripNewPayment();
            }
        });
}
```

I need to console the value so i can save stripe result reponse is only giving the last 4 digit of card and date only. I need to crack this i dont know how but i need to save these inputs

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that can be done for security reasons and [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/). [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) does not give you access to the raw card details. This is built to meet the requirements for PCI compliance and getting access to the raw card details would put you in a higher scope.

You should never need the raw card details from your customer. You can save the card on a Customer in your Stripe account so that you can charge them again in the future without having to ask for their card details again. This is documented in more details here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment